# Docker: cannot open port from container to host in ktor app

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, kotlin, ktor

I'm using Docker for windows. I have ktor Rest Api container that run a server, for example my server is run on port 5000. I have exposed this port on Dockerfile and I also have the Postgres container running on 5432. My code is running locally without docker and I can get response from chrome but on the docker `localhost:5000` I get

```
The localhost page isn’t working 
localhost didn’t send any data
```

**This is my DockerFile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

ENV APPLICATION_USER ktor
RUN adduser -D -g '' $APPLICATION_USER

RUN mkdir /app
RUN chown -R $APPLICATION_USER /app

USER $APPLICATION_USER

COPY ./build/libs/scienta-0.0.1.jar /app/scienta-0.0.1.jar
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["java", "-server", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-XX:InitialRAMFraction=2", "-XX:MinRAMFraction=2", "-XX:MaxRAMFraction=2", "-XX:+UseG1GC", "-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100", "-XX:+UseStringDeduplication", "-jar", "scienta-0.0.1.jar"]
```

**This is my Application.kt** which is meant to just return a text **Hello world** for the homepage

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)


@KtorExperimentalAPI
@KtorExperimentalLocationsAPI
fun Application.module() {
    install(Thymeleaf) {
        setTemplateResolver(ClassLoaderTemplateResolver().apply {
            prefix = "templates/thymeleaf/"
            suffix = ".html"
            characterEncoding = "utf-8"
        })
    }
    install(Locations) {
    }
    install(Sessions) {
        cookie<MySession>(name = "MY_SESSION") {
            cookie.extensions["SameSite"] = "lax"
        }
    }
    // initializes the data layer
    DatabaseFactory.init()
    val db = UserRepository()

    // handles authentication
    val jwtService = JwtService()
    val hashFunction = { s: String -> hash(s) }

    install(Authentication) {
        jwt("jwt") {
            verifier(jwtService.verifier) //specifies the verifier created in JwtService class
            realm = "rideShare Server"
            validate {
                // creates a method that runs each time the app needs to authenticate a call.
                val payload = it.payload
                val claim = payload.getClaim("id")
                val claimString = claim.asInt()
                val user = db.findUser(claimString) // 4
                user
            }
        }

    }


    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        gson {
        }
    }

    routing {
        users(db, jwtService, hashFunction)
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello :)")
        }
    }
}

const val API_VERSION = "/v1"
```

So it seems I have configured work "a little" but something wrong. Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: can you provide info how you start container? You should provide to option -p "5000:5000" when you create container

Comment: ooh, yes. It has worked now, Thank you